# Masterpage with a dynamic template

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, templates, master-pages

In MVC.NET, how should I dynamically populate the HTML structure from a database into a Masterpage where the first the template needs to wrap the masterpage contents?

AKA

```
   -- master page header stuff goes here --
   ... 
   -- Beginning of client template goes here --
   ...
   -- masterpage contents goes here --
   ... 
   -- End of client template goes here --
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed multiple content blocks in the master page:

```
   -- master page header stuff goes here --
   ... 
   -- content block 1 goes here --
   ...
   -- masterpage contents goes here --
   ... 
   -- content block 2 goes here --
```

Comment: Any problem with opening a div in the first and closing it in the second?

Comment: Since the end page will be correct, it shouldn't be a problem.  I'd try to avoid it personally, but there's nothing preventing you from doing it.